# MYSQL local data infile syntax error

Tags: mysql

I see that this question has been asked (multiple) times before, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

I created a database and table, and am now trying to load a local CSV file

> load data local infile '/Desktop/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx_xxx.csv'

MYSQL is giving me a syntax error message.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example doesn't specify the destination table name and is not terminated by a ';'. Also, you may want to drop the 'local' keyword, since you appear to be specifying the absolute path of the csv file. And it's a good idea to specify the field delimiter (e.g. comma).

As follows:

```
load data '/somedir/somefile.csv' 
 into table sometable
 fields terminated by ',';
```

In addition, you need to ensure that the field order in your file matches the default select order. If the field/column order doesn't match, then you will need to specify it. You will find all of the information you need about this in the [specification for this statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).